# Prove that $k + 1$ is the multiplicative inverse of 2, mod $m$.

Tags: proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Full question: Let $m = 2k + 1$ be an odd integer. Prove that $k + 1$ is the multiplicative inverse of 2, mod $m$.

My proof:

> By definition, if $k+1$ is the multiplicative inverse of 2, mod $m$, then $2(k+1)\equiv$ 1 mod(m). By the definition of $m$,  $2(k+1)\equiv$ 1 mod(2k+1). Therefore, $1-2(k+1)$ is a multiple of $2k+1$. We have to show that there exists an $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $n(2k+1) = 2(k+1)-1$.

Then I can go on to arrange the equation to show that $n=1$. I'm unsure as to whether or not that's enough. In general, I'm unsure about the procedure to prove something is the multiplicative inverse of something else. Here, if I just go by the definition and show that there is a $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies it, is it sufficient?

Comment: $2(k+1)=(2k+1)+1$

Comment: Yes, in your case it is sufficient.

Comment: Note that the if-then in your first sentence is the wrong way around for proving that $k+1$ is $2^{-1}$. Likewise, "therefore" in your third sentence seems to go in the opposite direction of what you need.

Comment: "sufficient"?  Way, way, way too complicated and unnecessarily involved, you mean.  $2$ and $k+1$ are multiplicative inverses because $2*(k+1) =2k + 2 = (2k+1) + 1 = m+ 1\equiv 1 \mod m$.  That is *ALL* you need to show.

Answer (score 1):

Two show two things (any things) are multiplicative inverses all you have to ever do is multiply them together and see that you get the identity.

So $2*(k+1) = 2k + 2 = m + 1 \equiv 1 \mod m$

End of story.  QED.  That's it.  Nothing more to see here folks.  Go home.